# Jqmath producing strange behaviour, incorrect rendering

Tags: javascript, html, mathml, jqmath

I am using `jqmath` for math rendering.Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqmath-etc-0.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>Displaying maths</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a≠0$, then:
$$∰f'(x)=\lim↙{h→0}{f(x+h)-f(x)}/h$$
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working perfectly in firefox but not in chrome 32 and IE 8.I checked the compatibility and it says `jqMath` is compatible with both the versions.So why it is not working?

The strange part is that the [home page of jqmath](http://www.mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) is working perfectly and when I write math expressions in the text area available for practice on the homepage, that is also being rendered properly.So where is the problem?

**EDIT**

The symbols are appearing but are scattered.It seems the problem is only with divide-by e.g. 2/3.If I visit homepage of `jqmath` using same version of chrome and write the same expressions in the test area provided, they are rendered correctly.

*Example1*

firefox(correct)
[image]
chrome(wrong)
[image]

*Example2*

firefox(correct)
[image]
chrome(wrong)
[image]

Comment: @DaveBarton:I think you can help (the author of jqmath)

Comment: “Incorrect rendering” and “not working” are not problem descriptions; explain how the rendering differs from the expected.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela:Please see the EDIT with diagrams.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I found the solution.I was not including the css file provided with jqmath.But shockingly why was it working in firefox?In fact, it was the reason I removed that css thinking it is not required.

Comment: I am trying to use jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js with jquery-1.12.1.min.js - i see errors in console - is this version incompatibility problem? If so, is there a jqmath version that works with jquery 1.12 version?

Comment: @InsaneCoder I have posted a question that you might have an answer to - please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526435/jqmath-not-loading-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqMath uses built-in MathML in browsers that have it, namely Firefox and recent versions of Safari (webkit). Sadly I.E. and Chrome are not so advanced (though old versions of I.E. could use the MathPlayer plugin for MathML), so jqMath has to use its own .css file to help with formatting. This explains the solution you found.

Comment: :Thanks Dave for the response.Special thanks for giving us the `jqmath`, an extremely useful library.

Comment: Dave Barton> Perhaps you have an answer to this question - pls see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526435/jqmath-not-loading-correctly