# Jqmath not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mathml, jqmath

I have included the following on my html page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jqmath-0.4.3.css"> 
<script src="../js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>M.MathPlayer = false; M.trustHtml = true;</script>
```

But when the page loads i see the following error in Javascript console:

```
jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular 
expression: /(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)|[\\`]([A-Za-z]+|.)|[ï¿½-ï¿½][ï¿½-ï¿½]|
\S[Ì€-Í¯á·€-á·¿âƒ-âƒ¿ï¸ -ï¸¯]*/: Range out of order in character class
```

I am using jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js with jquery-1.12.1.min.js.
**What am i missing here or could this be a version incompatibility issue?**
 jqmath 0.4.3 is the only version that seems to be available.

Comment: Do you have other scripts besides those?

Comment: Bikash> Yes i do - but they are unrelated simple ones that i wrote - and they are all after these scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Change your second `<script>` element to:

```
<script src="../js/jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

As alljamin suggests, you'll see basically this in COPY-ME.html. The key is the `charset="utf-8"`, required if you don't have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your html file (but you probably really should).

Comment: Dave> I added <meta charset="utf-8"> in html file, and also in script tag as suggested, but i still see the same error.

Comment: Dave> This is solved now. The problem was that i had copied content of jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js from web to my own editor(sublime) and saved it, and then used that - something went wrong there. So i took the original jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js from download zip and used it - and it worked fine! Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you did with your code.

If you download [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/downloads/mathscribe-win-0.4.3.zip) and open the `COPY_ME.html` in the downloaded folder, you should be able to see the structure of the `html` and how to make changes to it. Everything works fine there.

The example provided on jqMath official website uses jQuery 1.4.3 and your example uses jQuery 1.12.1, I am not sure but that could be the issue.

I hope this helps.